# need help writing an emacs function

Tags: emacs

I want to write an emacs function that does the following -

1) Start a new shell named "abc".
2) Change the dir "/opt/abc"
3) In the dir run a shell command "python abc.py"

I have written the following function -

```
(defun abc-server ()
 (interactive)
 (shell-command "cd /opt/abc/")
 (shell-command "python abc.py"))
```

The problem with the above -

1) It doesnt start a new shell
2) It doesnt change the dir.
3) When the cmd executes, it opens a browser window, which completely blocks any usage of emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `shell-command`'s docstring (`C-h f shell-command`):

> If COMMAND ends in ampersand, execute it asynchronously.
>   The output appears in the buffer `*Async Shell Command*'.
>   That buffer is in shell mode.

Also, combine it all into one command line.  `shell-command` makes a new shell every time, so the pwd will not persist from one invocation to another.

```
(defun abc-server ()
 (interactive)
 (shell-command "cd /opt/abc/; python abc.py &"))
```

Comment: Great that did solve the problem ! How do I set the buffer name to "abc-server"? This is the buffer for the async shell that is started.

Comment: [`rename-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

While @jpkotta's answer is good enough, a proper solution would use the [anync primitives of Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#Asynchronous-Processes).  For one thing, you can only have one async shell command running at a time, whereas you can have a large number of named subprocesses.

```
(defun abc-server ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Create buffer ahead of time so we can change its default directory
  (save-excursion
    (get-buffer-create "*abc-server*")
    (cd "/opt/abc") )
  (start-process "abc" "*abc-server*" "python" "abc.py") )
```

(I'm not altogether happy with the `save-excursion` hoop.  I was hoping I could simply let-bind `default-directory`, but that didn't seem to work as I had expected.  Alternatively, you could `(start-process "abc" "*abc-server*" "sh" "-c" "cd /opt/abc; python abc.py")`.)

If you need to extend the command further, I would argue that this is a more scalable platform than the quick and dirty async shell command approach, but if this is all you are ever going to need, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Perhaps the `cd` song and dance isn't actually necessary?  Would `python /opt/abc/abc.py` work?

Comment: By convention, temporary buffers you aren't supposed to want to edit or save have names like that.  It's a good convention, so I stuck to it, even though you wanted the buffer name to be just `abc-server`.